# How to generates curves from fabric pattern uploaded

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bezier

My main aim is to generate a such curves that it should get fit full sleeves of shirt as shown in image.[image]

I tried but still lines are not coming properly as expected

help me for this.

test fabric pattern is vertical fabrics of below shown image.
 what I got out out from scripted function is
[image]

I want more accurate to fit in sleeves shape
I have worked on following script.

```js
function curve2(event)
{   

   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  
    var getImagePath =  URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

     // just some inits for demo
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = slice;
    img.src = getImagePath;

    function slice() {
      c.width = img.height; 
   c.height = img.width; 
   
   
 

     // var step = Math.PI / h; // full circle / width of canvas
     // var scale = 75; // max displacement on y
  var w = c.width = this.height;
      var h = c.height = this.width+10;
    //var h = c.height = this.width+10;    //2
   //var h = c.height = this.width-40;
   
   //396
   
       var step = Math.PI / 500; // full circle / width of canvas
   // var step = Math.PI / 500; // 2
      var scale = 240; // max displacement on y
 //  var scale = 230; // 2
   // var scale = 200; // max displacement on y

      for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        ctx.drawImage(this,
          -1, y, w, 1, // source line from image
          Math.cos(step * y) * scale, y,w, 1); // displaced line
      }
    }

}
```

```html
 

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div id="ror">
<input type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" onchange="curve2(event)"  />
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. Could you reword it and tell us more about the input(s), desired output and how the presented code attempts to solve your issue?

Comment: updated. Please check  @le_m

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the maths to someone more qualified but I think the problem stems from the fact that you are offsetting each line in order to form a curve. I think you should rotate around the centre of curvature.

A rough illustration of what I mean:
[image: rotateRatherThanOffset]